# Margin top increases as I hover over the DIV 3 and DIV 4

Tags: html, css

I have the code as below but when I hover over DIV C and DIV D.
The margin-top I need to give increases.Can you please tell me how can this be
 fixed.Is it possible without using any javascript.

```css
.a {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  /* border: 5px solid yellow; */
  margin: 5px;
  background: orange;
}

.z {
  position: absolute;
  left: 220px;
  top: 0px;
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 500px;
}

.a:hover .z {
  /*  background: #f00; */
  display: block;
}


/* CSS Used by me */

.myactive:first-of-type {
  background: orange;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* CSS Used by me */

.myactive {
  background: orange;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="a">Div A
        <div class="z">
          <div class="myactive">Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="a">Div B
        <div class="z">
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="myactive">Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="a">Div C
        <div class="z">
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="myactive">Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="a">Div D
        <div class="z">
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="myactive">Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="a">Div E
        <div class="z">Div Z</div>
      </div>
      <div class="a">Div F
        <div class="z">Div Z</div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <!-- <div class="move">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do this without using any javascript.I tried using odd and even class to the CSS with no effect as it dynamically keeps adding the margin.

Comment: Updated the CSS for hover

Comment: here what you want to do?

Comment: I want the Active block should be in the same line as the left side div

Comment: I think you want the `.a` divs to be positioned as well. Make them `position:relative` for instance. Is that what you need to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for something like below?

```css
.a {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  /* border: 5px solid yellow; */
  margin: 5px;
  background: orange;
}

.z {
  position: absolute;
  left: 220px;
  top: 0px;
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 500px;
}

.a:hover .z {
  /*  background: #f00; */
  display: block;
}


/* CSS Used by me */

.myactive:first-of-type {
  background: orange;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.mynonactive {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}


/* CSS Used by me */

.myactive {
  background: orange;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="a">Div A
        <div class="z">
          <div class="myactive">Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="a">Div B
        <div class="z">
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="myactive">Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="a">Div C
        <div class="z">
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="myactive">Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="a">Div D
        <div class="z">
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="myactive">Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
          <div class="mynonactive">Not Active</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="a">Div E
        <div class="z">Div Z</div>
      </div>
      <div class="a">Div F
        <div class="z">Div Z</div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <!-- <div class="move">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```